# Writing a bash script to resize images, move them to another folder and rename them

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have a folder with approx 300 images that are 300x300 pixels each, they are images of artists. Inside that folder, I have created another folder called `60`.

I want to resize each image to 60x60 pixels, rename the file by appending `-60` to its name and move it into the `/60` folder.

So imagine I have an image called `bob-dylan.jpg`, I want that resized and then renamed to `bob-dylan-60.jpg` and then moved so that it sits in `/60/bob-dylan-60.jpg`.

I have attempted to do this myself by writing myself a shell script `batch-resize.sh`. I've made the script be an executable. The script attempts to use ImageMagick. Here's what I have so far.

**batch-resize.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in /mnt/c/Users/jwan/Pictures/bejebeje-artist-images/*; do
  mogrify -path /mnt/c/Users/jwan/Pictures/bejebeje-artist-images/60 -resize 60x60 $f
done
```

This resizes the images and moves them to the `/60` directory **but** it doesn't rename the file. I am really struggling with the rename.

I did search online, and I see a bunch of `%` symbols, but with no explanation.

I'd appreciate it if someone can show me how to build on what I have to also do the rename of the files but also explain **how** the rename is achieved.

Comment: This should help: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thanks @terdon, I am a bit of a n00b, but your link was helpful. I think I need something like `${f/%.jpg/-60.jpg}` but I'm not sure how I can fit that into my script. Where would it go? That code cannot replace the `$f` at the end my script cause it will then **look for** `bob-dylan-60.jpg` and that won't exist.

Comment: No, you would add an `mv` command afterwards. Sorry, I don't have time to post a full answer now (hence the link) but I'll try to later.

Comment: Oh I see, so the rename won't be part of the `mogrify` command, it'll be a separate command! Ok I'll try that.

Comment: I think that mogrify can take an output name as an argument, you could use it there too.

Comment: @terdon Apparently `mogrify` cannot take output file as argument, but `convert` that is also part of ImageMagic suite can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this as `bash scriptname /path/to/files`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$1"/*.{jpg,png}; do
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  base=$(basename "$f")
  convert -resize 60x60 "$f" "$1/60/${base%.*}-60.${base##*.}"
done
```

Add more extensions to the braces if needed.

`convert` takes an input file `$f` and places the result of resizing it in the directory `$1/60` (`$1` is the argument).

- `[ -f "$f" ] || continue` skips the operation in case `f` is not a regular file. You surely do not want to resize a directory.
- `basename` gets removes the path from the file name. E.g., `a/b/c.jpg` becomes `c.jpg`.
- `${base##*.}` removes all up to the last dot from the file's basename. Thus it gets the extension.
- `${base%.*}` removes all after the extension.

Comment: Thanks @Quasimodo. My `batch-resize.sh` sits in my home folder '~', can I keep the file where it is, but run it against `/mnt/c/Users/jwan/Pictures/bejebeje-artist-images/*`?

Comment: @J86 You are welcome. Yes, by introducing an argument, you can. Check out the edit.